# ASP.net c# command.ExecuteNonQuery not saving complete record

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a table ITL_ReportLog in which I have to save records of every time report is printed, when I write command with

```
string tempSql = "";
    if (logCheck == "true") {
        tempSql = reportSql.Replace("'","''");
        tempSql = "INSERT INTO ITL_ReportLog ([username],[runOn],[query]) VALUES ('" + nvc["login"] + "','"+DateTime.Now+"','" + tempSql + "')";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(tempSql, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    conn.Close();
    Response.Write(tempSql);
```

It show correct result as show in image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4xWs.png)

But after inserting when I check in sql it shows half query

```
SELECT 
  'CARTZ Link' AS CompanyName,'Mezzanine Floor, 23-C, Lane 8, 
   Sehar Comm. Area Phase 7 DHA Karachi Pakistan'AS CompanyAddress,
   'admin' login_user,'crm.cartzlink.local' selhost,'admin' sellogin,
   'LEDGER' selreportTitle,'V' selledgerDate,'01-Jul-2015' selfrmDate,
   '23-Sep-2017' seltoDate,'' selaccountId,'' selac_accountId_ac,
   '' selcity,'' selarea,'' selsalesmanId,'S' seldst,
   'A' seldisplayTransaction,'' selgodownId,'D' selsortBy,
   '1' selcurrencyId,'gr_lgr_fcr' seltoprint,'Report
```

but when I run query manually it saves perfectly

Comment: Your column size is too small may be, then your insert is truncated

Comment: column size is 4000, by the way trim worked for me using cmd = new SqlCommand(tempSql.Trim(), conn);

Answer (score 0):

Your column size is too small may be, then your insert is truncated. try to resize your column query into ITL_ReportLog  table, or try to trim your variable

Comment: column size is varchar(4000)

Comment: it was a size question then but just not trimmed variable ;)

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting through code, try to replace the Single quote character with some other character. Later on update it,using replace function.

Comment: It will give error while insertion because I am using same query in cmd = new SqlCommand(tempSql, conn);

Comment: tempSql.Trim() saves the day :-)